# Using Javascript to hide textfields

Tags: javascript, html

If a user selects a certain `option value` in one `select` field, how do you then make a text field `hidden`, s it will not be needed. This must be done before the form is submitted?

For example in the following select field, a user select chooses `value='a'` then how would this text field become hidden:

```
     <select name="form" id="aForm">
        <option value="a">choice1</option>
        <option value="b">choice2</option>
        <option value="c">choice3</option>
     </select>

     <input type="text" style="width:285px" name="textField" id="textField"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#aForm").on("change", function() { 
    if ($(this).val() == "a") 
        $("#textField").hide();
    else 
        $("#textField").show(); 
});
```

Here is also a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beradrian/PcLgu/1/)

I assumed that you will show the textfield for any other value than a.

If you're using plain JavaScript and not jQuery

```
function hideTF() {
    var s = document.getElementById("aForm");
    document.getElementById("textField").style.display 
         = (s.selectedIndex > 0  && s.options[s.selectedIndex] == 'a'
         ? "none" : "block");
}
var s = document.getElementById("aForm");
if (s.attachEvent)
    s.attachEvent("onchange", hideTF);
else
    s.addEventListener("change", hideTF, false);
```

Comment: Nice solution Adrian, but he is not using jQuery.

Comment: I modified my solution for plain JavaScript too.

Comment: And also made it to work even if the option 'a' is not the first one.

Comment: Thanks...I've used the JQuery solution and included the code in the html page in `script tags`, but it doesn't hide the text field.

Comment: `if(this.val())` should be `if($(this).val())` or `if(this.value)`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera, Thanks for the suggestion, but that still did not get it to work.

Comment: Did you add/load `jQuery` ?

Comment: Yes I've added jquery: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`

Comment: One more thing. At first you will have choice 1 selected by default. Selected choice 2 and then 1 again. The textfield will hide.

Comment: Did you put it inside `$(document).ready(function(){ // code goes here });`

Comment: @SheikhHeera: Thanks that was the problem. Works perfectly now. Thanks for both of yours help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variation of this:

```
var selection = aForm.selectedIndex,
    field = document.getElementById('textField');

if ( selection === x ) {

    field.style.display = "block"; // or visibility = "hidden"

}
```

This should be enclosed in an `.onchange` event. `aForm.selectedIndex` is the index of the corresponding `<option>` element that is selected.